# How to organize angular module dependencies

Tags: javascript, angularjs, module, coding-style, dependencies

I use the application component segmentation logic when creating my angular application, which is to say I have the following folder structure:

```
app.module.js
app.config.js
components
---- core
-------- core.module.js
-------- etc...
---- component1
-------- component1.module.js
-------- etc...
---- component2
-------- component2.module.js
-------- etc...
---- etc...
shared
---- sharedComponent1
-------- etc...
---- etc...
assets
```

Now, I group all my components into my `app.module.js` file and that's pretty much all that file is there for. My `component1.module.js` will list dependencies that module requires and so on. Now, I realize that it sort of doesn't matter where I define module dependencies and that I can put all my dependant module, regardless of component in the `app.module.js` file, but that's simply not clean nor does it offer good modularity.

That being said, I'm not sure what to do with modules that are used in every, or almost every other module, like modules for localization for example. The real problem here isn't that the whole app uses that module, it's that that universal module needs to be configured, so I was thinking about putting that dependency, and the required configuration, in the `core.module.js` and `core.config.js` file, respectively.

I've read a lot about angular best practices, but I wasn't able to find something concerning module dependency organization which, I suppose, is because angular puts all the modules in a "big box" anyway.

Another approach would be to create a shared component that focuses on incorporating that particular dependency, or group of dependencies into angular, and then have my other components depend on that component, but I'm not sure if this is too much.

Comment: Two problems here... 1) you forgot to ask a question and 2) anything related to organizing like this is all opinion based and therefore off topic here. Try : https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide

Comment: Well the question is sort of in the title, and while I agree that it's not a "how to fix bug" question which has a direct answer, best practices don't necessarily have to be opinion based if there is strong reasoning behind it.

Comment: There is no *one size fits all* so yes it is opinion based as well as many other factors that are far too broad to get into within scope of the ***question***

Answer (score 1):

I structure my modules as follows. The only real difference between my structure and yours is that all core/shared are basically the same thing. I have a component folder for each individual module of the application. Anything that isn't part of an individual component goes in core. The things that almost every single component use go in core too, as they are then a core piece of your application.

In my opinion, as long as you are breaking the application into components/angular.modules, keeping core code separate, and the organization is clear and easy to understand, its perfectly acceptable

```
core
----app
--------app.module.js
--------app.config.js

----util
--------util.module.js

components
----comp1
--------comp1.module.js
--------comp1.etc
----comp2
--------comp2.module.js
```